# Repeated background affects TextViews height

Tags: android

I have a Image that I want to repeat on the x axis to match the width.

**repeating_section_header.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/table_section_header_light"
    android:tileMode="repeat" />
```

so far so good.
Now I set this as background of a `TextView`:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/row_headline_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/repeating_section_header"
    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="14sp" 
    android:textStyle="bold"/>
```

But now the the TextViews height is the height of `@drawable/table_section_header_light`, even if I have set TextViews height to `wrap_content`.

Any idea how to fix that (make the TextViews height to wrap content)

Comment: Depending on how your image looks, you could use a smaller nine patch drawable instead of that bitmap.

Comment: Not sure if this is appropriate in your situation, but if the textview is always going to be a fixed number of lines, set the height to a fixed value in dp.

Comment: nine patch cant be used, because there is a background pattern in the graphic that can not be streched and I would not declare the height with concrete dp values, I want to use wrap_content

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is by programmatically determining the height of the textview with just the text, and fixing the height, and the setting the background drawable. This way, it will adjust to the height of your textview depending on how many lines is used.

Java:

```
TextView v = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.row_headline_text);
v.setText("<your text here>");
v.measure(android.view.View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, android.view.View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);

android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = v.getLayoutParams();
params.height = v.getMeasuredHeight();
v.setLayoutParams(params);
v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.table_section_header_light);
```

xml:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/row_headline_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Comment: is there not a easier way? I do not want to do it in code, is there not a way to do that in xml?

Comment: @sockeqwe Seems like everyone has a programmatic method such as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14976776/background-drawables-define-view-size) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8842484/tiled-background-is-pushing-its-view-size)

Answer (score 0):

If you okay with this technique, try it:

1. Wrap your TextView into a RelativeLayout.
2. Add a View as the first child in this RelativeLayout. (let the TextView be the second child)
3. Remove your background from the TextView to this new View
4. Set the layout params of your TextView (AlignLeft, AlignRight, AlignTop, AlignBottom) to `@+id/row_headline_text`

This should work. If your TextView's parent is already a RelativeLayout, you won't need the new RelativeLayout.